# Triggering Isotope

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, jquery-isotope

Apologies if you've seen this before. This is my third attempt at this issue and so far the majority of the work has been isolating what the issue actually is.

My project is to load a series of images and provide a facility to upload more images via a Fancybox iframe. After upload the page would call a function that does an AJAX request of the new list of images, reload them into a DIV and lay them out with Isotope.

If I trigger the function from a  tag with onclick it works fine. But if I trigger it from Fancybox's afterClose function the images load outside the DIV and isotope doesn't lay them out. I have also confirmed that triggering the function from a button doesn't work either.

I have built a demo using the actual code here:
http://photopedia.com.au/mem/login.taf?_function=test
For the sake of simplicity it avoids the upload process. It just opens a Fancybox that asks you to close it, which triggers the load photos() function.

And here is the code:

```
<style>
.element{
width:230px;
height:230px;
//display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

<script src="/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


    <!-- jQuery with jQuery Easing, and jQuery Transit JS -->
    <script src="/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jquery/jquery-transit-modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function loadphotos(){
var $container = $('#container');

$container.load('/mem/memphotos.taf',function(){
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    })
});
});
};

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(".lightbox").fancybox({
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    }); 

$("#uploadphoto").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 740,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        'afterClose' : function () { 
            loadphotos();
            }
    });



</script>

 <div class=title>
 <h1>Photos</h1>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>



<br>


<!-- if profile name is blank -->
<a href="" onclick="loadphotos();">Load photos</a> <- works

<br>
<br>

<button onclick="loadphotos();">Load photos</button> <- doesn't work

<br>
<br>

<a href='/mem/upload_imagetest.html' id='uploadphoto' class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">
Upload a photo
</a> <- doesn't work

<br>
<br>

<div id="container" style="border:1px dotted red;">



</div>


<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadphotos();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your button woks with the function well. The problem is when the `<a>` tag is clicked, the page is redirected to the same page with your result. Like a page refresh.

When you press the button it calls to the function and completes the ajax request. But the required style(s) not applied to the parent container and to the child containers. because the all html part replaced by the ajax  request results. look like you have to change the applying style concept as well.

Button is a form element and you can see the behavior of the button if the contents is placed inside the `<form>` as follows. when you press the button the page will post and redirect to the same page because the action is not given.

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      place Your contents here
    </form>
</body>
```

The requirement is depend when to use a `<button>` or an `<a>` tag on the page.

And also remove all external style sheets and js files and inline java-script parts from the from `<body>` tag, and place them inside `<head>` tag.

Load CSS first and then java-script files
Load major libraries first like jQuery and the other plugins as they depend on the other libraries as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen">

<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

By doing so you can reduce unexpected behaviors and focus on real problems.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the feedback. Some things to work on.